# loading JSON file into variable at startup of chrome app

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-app

I'm writing a chrome app and I want to store a lot of the configuration defaults in json file(s) along side the rest of my assets.  I can do an AJAX request for them but since I can't do anything before these load is there a better way?  Perhaps a manifest option?  I could always put settings in another .js file too but that seems dirty.

Edit: I'm using jQuery as well in case it includes some nice functionality.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just include a `<script src="myconfig.js"></script>` in your app's page?

Comment: Specifically, something like var config = JSON.parse("{...}");

Comment: I don't like the idea that it could be evaluating code in a config file.  Though, as an asset, "myconfig.js" would be 100% under my control so maybe its okay.